# how do i add data to django model according to choices

Tags: django, python-3.x

suppose i have a model and a view:

```
class DataA(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    TYPE = (
        ("N", "Select Type"),
        ("S", "Student"),
        ("P", "Professional"),
    )
    data_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=TYPE,
        default="N",
        validators=[type_val],
    )
    student = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)
    professional = models.CharField(
        max_length=60, default=None
    )

class DataACreateView(CreateView):
    model = DataA
    fields = "__all__"
    template_name = "api/view.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        p_type = self.request.POST["data_type"]
        print(p_type)
        if p_type is "S":
            print("data is S")
            # self.request.POST['professional'] = None
        elif p_type is "P":
            print("data is P")
            # self.request.POST['student'] = None
        else:
            print("data is SOme")
            # raise ValidationError('Please select a valid value')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("create"))
```

I tried this; it says values are immutable and I understand it, but how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here...

- First: the name of your model – `DataA` is simply not descriptive at all.
- Using `auto_now=True` will update the date every time the object is saved; that's probably not what you want for a field called `created`. Try `auto_now_add=True` instead.
- The `TYPE` list should probably be called `TYPES` (as it is a collection).
- The type list should *not* contain invalid choices. I assume "Select Type" is not a valid choice. (For forms, you can set the select field's `empty_label` to "Select Type", which is probably what you want.)
- If you want your CharFields to be able to be blank, add `blank=True` and get rid of the (invalid) default value `None`.
- You can't safely use `is` to compare strings. In fact, unless you're very aware of what you're doing, never use `is`.  Use `==` instead. (`is` is the identity comparison operator, not the equality comparison operator.)

Then to the issue at hand.

It's more idiomatic Django to have the additional logic for a form in a form class to begin with (in [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), for instance); this way you can test the form without using the view, and you can reuse the form.

(However, if I'm guessing your intention right, you actually want this logic (that when the type is P, the `student` field should be empty and vice versa for S/`professional`) to be in the [model's `clean()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean). We'll do it in the form for illustrative purposes though.)

Something like this should do the trick – though be warned that I've dry-coded this, so there may be silly mistakes or typos.

```
class DataA(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    TYPES = (("S", "Student"), ("P", "Professional"))
    data_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=TYPES
    )  # Having no default makes choosing a choice mandatory
    student = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    professional = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)


class DataAForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DataA
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields["data_type"].empty_label = "Select Type"

    def clean(self):
        p_type = self.cleaned_data["data_type"]
        if p_type == "S":
            self.cleaned_data["professional"] = ""
        elif p_type == "P":
            self.cleaned_data["student"] = ""
        return self.cleaned_data


class DataACreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "api/view.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("create")
```

Comment: sir I am new to python I have recently created one website just for testing puspose url is 103.54.100.10 have a look...thank you for you response this will help me lot